What does the Brazilian law say about the promotion of federal civil servants?
Introduction. The Brazilian Act 8112 from 1990 regulates the position of civil servants of the federal government.  Article 10 determines how a person earns a position---it has to be through a public exam in which people are ranked.

Art. 10.  A nomeação para cargo de carreira ou cargo isolado de provimento efetivo depende de prévia habilitação em concurso público de provas ou de provas e títulos, obedecidos a ordem de classificação e o prazo de sua validade.

Article 10 then observes that there are other ways of getting a position with the federal government such as being promoted---the details of which will be determined by a separate act.

Parágrafo único.  Os demais requisitos para o ingresso e o desenvolvimento do servidor na carreira, mediante promoção, serão estabelecidos pela lei que fixar as diretrizes do sistema de carreira na Administração Pública Federal e seus regulamentos.

Question. Has this separate act ever been published?  Where can I find it?

Probably not, as this law would certainly be required in the entrance exams.

That's good thinking.  Thanks!  (I'd accept that as an answer.)

It's hard to prove a negative, but there are some indications that that law has never passed:

That law would have many repercussions in the public sector, but I couldn't find any news mentioning that.
That law would certainly be required in the entrance exams for public servant jobs, but I could not find it mentioned in an announcement or some preparatory course.
This article and this study (both in Portuguese) suggest that that law has not been enacted.

